# Chain map of isomorphic chain complexes

Tags: algebraic-topology

If we know that the homology groups of two chain complex are isomorphic to each other, can we say that there is a chain map between these two chain complexes？ If so, how can we define the chain map?

Comment: There is always the zero map of complexes.  Do you mean must there exist a homotopy equivalence between the two complexes, that is, a chain map inducing isomorphisms on the homology groups?

Comment: @Jared: homotopy equivalence is a strictly stronger condition than quasi-isomorphism.

Comment: Yes, you're right Qiaochu.  I should have said quasi-isomorphism.